# Finding the path traveled by a material point using the function of its speed.

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, trigonometry

Suppose we know a material point traveled some path $f(t)$ on a plane (in 2D space) and we were able to map its speed in relationship to time to the function $g(t) = sin(t) + 2$. The material point has the weight of $1kg$ and at $f(0) = 0$. We assume there to be no air resistance and gravity of $g = 9.8m/s^2$. I am trying to find out whether it is possible to find this path $f(t)$ only knowing this information.

Will there be multiple paths? Do we need more information? - I'm not necessarily looking for an in depth solution, just a push in the right direction or a confirmation that this is realistically possible. Thank you!

Comment: Is $x$ a two-dimensional position vector in 2D space? If so, how do you evaluate $\sin(x)$? If not, how do you interpret $f(x)$? Is it supposed to give the y-coordinate for a given x-coordinate? Or would it be better to phrase it as $f(t)$, where $t$ is the time elapsed?

Comment: You are right, it would be better to phrase it as $f(t)$ where t is the time elapsed. Similarly $g(x)$ should be $g(t)$ then. This more accurately states what I am looking for. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: Great! Since the point is travelling in 2D space, I assume $f(t)$ spits out the 2-dimensional position  of the point at time $t$. Currently the speed $g(t)$ is a scalar function; but if the point is moving in 2D, we need to know velocity; i.e. speed and direction. This could be done by modifying $g(t)$ to return a two-dimensional velocity vector.